# Javascript: check for key in array that might not exist

Tags: javascript

Say `boundEvents` is an array that might or might not exist. If it doesn't exist, then the following code will return 'undefined':

```
console.log(typeof boundEvents);
```

Fine. That is exactly what I want. Now say I want to check that theoretical array for the existence of a *key* which might or might not exist.

```
console.log(typeof boundEvents['click']);
```

Uh oh:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

Fair enough, javascript. So let's check to see if the array exists, before we check for the key:

```
if(typeof boundEvents != 'undefined'){
    console.log(typeof boundEvents['click']);
}
```

Working again, but I'm wondering if there is a way to eliminate the `if` statement and just check on the existence of `boundEvents['click']` directly, in one step?

Thanks!

EDIT: complete answer, combined from below:

```
var boundEvents = boundEvents || {};   
console.log(boundEvents.hasOwnProperty('click'));
```

Comment: nope, you need the if statement.

Comment: Nope, you've gotta check each layer.

Comment: You could do `console.log(typeof boundEvents != 'undefined' && typeof boundEvents['click'])`. Whether that's more readable is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
boundEvents = boundEvents || {};
console.log(boundEvents['click']);
```

or in a single line:

```
console.log((boundEvents || {})['click']);
```

Comment: Was just about to write that ha ha :-) But shorter is not always better, So in reality suggested if

Comment: Simple (and kind of obvious, now that I'm looking at it), clean, still explicitly explains that boundEvents might be undefined. Thanks!

Comment: This is the answer to the question, but I also like crowebird's suggestion.

Comment: Note that `{}` creates a new object, which increases memory usage. You could use `console.log((boundEvents || 0).click)`, taking advantage of the fact that `0` does not have a `click` property.

Comment: @RaymondChen: You are correct, although in this case I'll stick to code readability rather than trying to save at most a few bytes of memory...

Comment: If your goal is readability, then use `console.log(boundEvents && boundEvents.click)`. Note also that your version has a side effect: If `boundEvents` is not defined or is defined with falsy value, then your first version changes its value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an explicit `true / false` then:

```
(boundEvents || {}).hasOwnProperty('click')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check each layer ending on the variable you want.  This will default to undefined if everything is false.

```
( (typeof boundEvents !== "undefined") && boundEvents['click']) || undefined
```